# Slim Application Error A website error has occurred. , Slim can't get my function

Tags: php, sql, backend, slim

Everytime I open in the browser localhost/test it shows : Slim Application Error A website error has occurred. Im trying to print all the data inside my table in sql , but it just return the same error.
This is my first time using php and slim framework , the other times I used node.js.
can someone help , thank you.

index.php :

```
<?php
namespace src;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

use handles\userhandle;

$app = new \Slim\app;

$user = new userhandle();

$app->get('/test' , function(Request $request, Response $response){
    global $user;
    $user->ALL($request, $response);
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
?>
```

useHandle.php :

```
<?php
namespace handles;

use connection\Sql;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

class userhandle {
    private $sql;

    public function ALL(Request $request, Response $response){
        $this->sql = new sql();
        
        $stmt = $this->sql -> comand(
        "SELECT * FROM substancias"
        );
        $response->getBody()->write($stmt);
        return $response;
    } 
}
?>
```

sql.php :

```
<?php

namespace connection{

class Sql{     
        public function comand($query){
            $stmt = $this->conn -> prepare($query);
            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should also show the error message.

Comment: it just shows : Slim Application Error A website error has occurred.

Comment: This is not the real error message. You may try to enable the error reporting to see the details. [Read more](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/error-handling.html)